# Create an Excel file using vbscripts

Tags: vbscript

How do I create an excel file using `VBScript`? I searched the net but it just mentions opening an existing file.

This is the extraction from the Internet shown below

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Scripts\New_users.xls")
```

I want to know how do you create a new excel file or `.xls` using `vbscript`?

Thanks and regards

Maddy

Comment: Which version of Excel? What flavour of VBscript? Where are you planning on running the VBScript from?

Comment: YogoZuno,I am using VB 6.0 for scripting.Can u please suggest me any good link where we could study vb scripting by ourselves.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a sample code

```
strFileName = "c:\test.xls"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
objWorkbook.SaveAs(strFileName)

objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot shoban.Can u suggest me a  better link where we could learn vb scripting

Answer (score 5):

```
set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
set objWorkbook=objExcel.workbooks.add()
objExcel.cells(1,1).value = "Test value"
objExcel.cells(1,2).value = "Test data"
objWorkbook.Saveas "c:\testXLS.xls"
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.workbooks.close
objExcel.quit
set objExcel = nothing `
```

Answer (score 2):

```
'Create Excel

Set objExcel = Wscript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.visible = True

Set objWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Add

objWb.Saveas("D:\Example.xlsx")

objExcel.Quit
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = true
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

intRow = 2
dim ch
objWorksheet.Cells(1,1) = "Name"
objWorksheet.Cells(1,2) = "Subject1"
objWorksheet.Cells(1,3) = "Subject2"
objWorksheet.Cells(1,4) = "Total"
for intRow = 2 to  10000 
name= InputBox("Enter your name")
sb1 = cint(InputBox("Enter your Marks in Subject 1"))
sb2 = cint(InputBox("Enter your Marks in Subject 2"))
total= sb1+sb2+sb3+sb4
objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = name
objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = sb1
objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value = sb2
objExcel.Cells(intRow, 4).Value = total
ch = InputBox("Do you want continue..? if no then type no or y to continue")
    If ch = "no" Then Exit For 
Next

objExcel.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

MsgBox "Done"
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

This code creates the file temp.xls in the desktop but it uses the SpecialFolders property, which is very useful sometimes!

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")

set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
objWorkbook.SaveAs(strDesktop & "\temp.xls")
```