# How to generate an excel(.XLS) file with a VB script?

Tags: sql-server, vba, vbscript, export-to-excel, dts

I want to create an excel file with `.xls` by using VBScript.

Because I want to create a DTS package for our requirement. DTS accepts excel files which has `.xls` extension only.

Any help?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are talking about here. What other suffix would an Excel file have? Are you worried about the newer Excel file format?

Answer (score 2):

The following code would create an Excel file with a `.xls` extension, if that's all you really need to know.

Modified slightly from Microsoft's developer support (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221273%28v=office.11%29.aspx):

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set NewBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
With NewBook
    .Title = "My Title"
    .SaveAs "MyFile.xls"
End With
```

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, Thanks! I forgot to remove that from the original code from MicroSoft, which was for VBA. I've edited it to be a working sample.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to create and excel file with vbscript provided excel is installed on the same machine the script runs on. Basically, you would use the excel COM object, for sample code check out: [Create an Excel file using vbscripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123605/create-an-excel-file-using-vbscripts)

Hope that helps...