# I would like to reference a new excel object created with shell

Tags: shell, excel, vba

I have Excel 2003 and 2010 on my machine so when I use `set xlapp = new excel.application` it creates a new Excel 2003 application. My work around is to create a new Excel 14 application using shell. It works but I need to open an existing excel file to reference the object later.

I would like to reference the object without opening an existing file. Is there any way to reference the new Excel app without using the file name. Below is code for an existing file. Please show me the correct way to do this.

```
Dim MyApp As Excel.Application
TaskID = Shell("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE  "C:\Book2.xlsx", vbNormalFocus)
Set MyApp = GetObject("C:\Book2.xlsx").Application
```

Comment: `Set MyApp = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create it ans close Excel ...

```
strFileName = "c:\test.xls"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True ' You don't have to use this property....

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
objWorkbook.SaveAs(strFileName)

objExcel.Quit
```

Would that work for you? See here original solution: [Create an Excel file using vbscripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123605/create-an-excel-file-using-vbscripts)

Comment: My problem is that I only have one clsid. I don't want to create a new excel application in the conventional manner because it always defaults to 2003 (even w/ excel.application.14). I need to use shell. Just wondering if there is a way to reference the object created using shell without opening an existing file. Thanks.

Comment: Good, if this worked for you please consider marking my answer as good to go so the other users could find it easier...